# How do I instantiate a CommandLineRunner in a controller action, along with all of the @Autowired properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have

```
@Component
public class WeeklyReport implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private RecipientMapper recipientMapper;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        String[] recipients = recipientMapper.all();
```

---

```
@Controller
public class MyController extends BaseController implements ErrorController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/weekly-report-run", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView weeklyReportRun(WeeklyReport weeklyReport) {
        try {
            weeklyReport.run();
```

But I get a NullPointerException at recipientMapper.all(). How can I instantiate the CommandLineRunner so that all @Autowired fields are auto-wired, and I can re-use code by calling it both from the command line and also from the controller? I thought that by specifying it as a parameter to the controller method, Spring Boot would instantiate the correct object, and all the sub-fields.

Spring Boot 1.5.19.

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
@Autowired
private WeeklyReport weeklyReport;
```

To the controller and removed it from the controller method arguments and it worked. The action method was able to see the auto-wired class variable.